# Invoking Playwright browser install behind a proxy with a custom certificate

Tags: powershell, playwright

I am getting an error trying to invoke playwright.pas1 install command from a company's laptop that's connected to the outside world via proxy server.

```
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to download chromium v978106, caused by
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
```

I had a similar issue with pip and npm before but was able to resolve them by adding proxy configs to the tool's config file. How can make it work with Playwright (PowerShell)?

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link and try

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/browsers#chromium

Install behind a firewall or a proxy
By default, Playwright downloads browsers from Microsoft CDN.

Sometimes companies maintain an internal proxy that blocks direct access to the public resources. In this case, Playwright can be configured to download browsers via a proxy server.

PowerShell
$env:HTTPS_PROXY="https://192.0.2.1"
pwsh bin\Debug\netX\playwright.ps1 install

Comment: Where this `PowerShell $env:HTTPS_PROXY="https://192.0.2.1" pwsh bin\Debug\netX\playwright.ps1 install` command should be run? Power Shell is throwing an error on `pwsh`

Comment: refer to: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/browsers#install-behind-a-firewall-or-a-proxy